# What relation does ergodicity have to the multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 in Markov matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

We know that positive semi-definite Markov matrices have eigenvalues $\lambda\leq |1|$ and if the multiplicity of $|\lambda| = 1$ is 1, after raising the matrix to a high power, the matrix will converge to a matrix where each row is the eigenvector associated with the  eigenvalue. This is because $M^kv = c_1\lambda_1^kx_1 + ... + c_n\lambda_n^kx_n$ if we write v in terms of eigenbases $v_i = \sum c_i\lambda_ix_i$, and eigenvalues with magnitude lower than 1 converge to 0.
I am interested in why ergodicity relates to eigenvalues? What about aperiodicity and irreducibility points to Markov matrices having just one eigenvalue of magnitude 1?
I feel like I have an intuitive understanding of why both are required for a limiting distribution to exist: irreducibility allows the chain to not get "stuck" in different specific states, so then the stationary distribution must be unique, and aperiodicity disallows oscillation, allowing the stationary distribution to exist, so then we have a single stationary distribution the matrix converges to over time, which is the limiting distribution. And separately, having just one eigenvalue of magnitude 1 essentially implies we have just one steady state that does not oscillate, allowing convergence.
But I have absolutely no intuition on the math that ties these two perspectives on the existence of the limiting distribution together...

Comment: An example but with 0 eigenvalues : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452570/steady-states-of-stochastic-matrix-with-multiple-eigenvalues#comment9593086_3452570

Comment: Your first sentence and second sentence are both false.  What text are you using?

Comment: Introduction to linear algebra, Strang, chpt 8.3 @user8675309

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than to re-read the book.  There is no reason for all eigenvalues  to be real, so the statement $\lambda \leq \vert 1\vert =1$ doesn't make sense; convergence is not guaranteed since periodicity is an issue. Maybe you meant to say only one eigenvalue (with multiplicity) on the unit circle. Your second sentence asserts that a Markov matrix is diagonalizable which is also false.

Comment: Oh yes, I think the chapter is written under the assumption that the matrices are positive semi-definite, I've updated the question. But even just looking at this specific case of Markov matrices, everything I was asking about holds and irreducibility and aperiodicity is still a sufficient condition and I would like to understand why. Convergence is not guaranteed even if ≤|1| and obviously eigenvalue multiplicities of greater than 1 still exist.